# Firebase deploy successful but some files missing

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I successfully deployed my site to Firebase using the Firebase CLI but when I try to load a particular page, it doesn't render correctly and in the console I get a 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404()' error. The missing files are CardJs' card-js.min.css and card-js.min.js. what do I do?

firebase.json (from the comments):

```
{
    "database": {
        "rules": "database.rules.json"
    },
    "hosting": {
        "public": "Auction",
        "ignore": ["firebase.json", "/.*", "**/node_modules/"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show you firebase.json content, structure of the working directory and index.html file

Comment: {
  
 "database": 
 {
    
  "rules": "database.rules.json"
  
 },
  
 "hosting": {
    
  "public": "Auction",
    
  "ignore": [
                               "firebase.json",
      
    "**/.*",
      
    "**/node_modules/**"
    
  ]
  
 }

}

Comment: I forgot to add, it works fine when I'm serving it locally

Comment: Is that card-js some vendor code or it is your file?

Comment: It's vendor code

Comment: How is that script added into app? Is it also in Auction folder btw?

Comment: Yeah, both files are in the 'Auction/plugins/CardJs/' directory

Comment: How your scripts are added in the index html? I expect that there is incorrect path given.

Comment: Just fixed it! Turns out it was from the link to the file as 'Js' != 'JS'. Was using the latter. Thanks Artem

Comment: Could you please describe the exact issue and the solution in the answer area? Actually answer your question yourself.
It will help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

The link was not found because it was pointing to 'path/to/CardJS' instead of 'path/to/CardJs'. It somehow worked when served locally because according to some people, Windows is case insensitive.